# jQuery to add comma's after elements on drag, drop, copy or paste?

Tags: jquery

I'm using the code below to dynamically add a highlight class to my span tags that are children of my "my_related_kw" div.

I'm currently adding a hard coded comma after each span tag, so that when the keywords are copied and pasted into the "Tags" input field, they are separated with commas.

However, I don't really want the comma's to show up on screen. Can I use jQuery to add the commas only when the content is pasted or when the copy or drag event is triggered?

```
var html = jQuery('#content').html().toLowerCase();
    jQuery(".my_related_kw").find("span").filter(function() {
        return html.indexOf(jQuery(this).html()) != -1;
    }).each(function() {
        jQuery(this).addClass('highlight');
    });
},
```

Comment: C'mon man, you've been around long enough to know you should format your code...

Comment: @Jared, thanks for the reformat. I didn't recognize it was off.

Answer (score 0):

Use a hidden field containing your keywords with commas. Your input field could reflect the hidden field, just format it for display by removing commas.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the commas to be there so that the user can copy/paste the text, then put the commas inside spans with a css style that makes them fully transparent.  then they will be there and get copied but will not be visible.